# WSO2 EI JSONBuilder configuration

Tags: json, xml, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have this xml which needed to be processed and converted to JSON:

```
<jsonObject>
    <number>1234</number>
    <emptyString/>
    <string>hello</string>
</jsonObject>
```

When it runs through JsonStreamBuilder like this:

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
```

I get JSON like that:

```
{
  "number":1234,
  "emptyString": null,
  "string":"hello"
}
```

So I am wondering is there any way that I can configure JsonStreamBuilder to treat empty tag not as null, but as empty string, furthermore I want numbers to be treated as strings as well.

Maybe I can modify the default XML to fit my needs?

BTW I am using WSO2 EI 6.1.1

Answer (score 4):

The default behavior of JsonFormatter is to allow primitive types in the JSON output. This means any content that is a valid number will be represented in the JSON message as a number.

As a solution for this issue, you could disable, the conversion to primitive type after adding below property to the **synapse.properties** file of **EI_HOME/conf** directory.

```
synapse.commons.json.output.autoPrimitive=false
```

However, this property is a global property, so it will be effected to all the services (Proxy services and the APIs). So this means any string that is a valid number will not be converted to a number.

According to your issue, you need to disable the conversion of String to Integer. You could solve this, adding below properties into **EI_HOME/conf/synapse.properties** file also.

```
synapse.commons.json.output.autoPrimitive=true

synapse.commons.json.output.disableAutoPrimitive.regex=^[1-9]*$
```

In this case, auto primitive disables for the numbers only.

**NOTE**: Once autoprimitive is enabled, some fields can be excluded from the auto primitive functionality based on the regular expression defined in the synapse.properties file.

- And the empty tag as the not null issue, you can resolve following the above-mentioned blog post.

Comment: Great explanation, but how would OP exclude empty strings from the auto primitive functionality? Since that seems to be what he needs

Comment: You can follow https://medium.com/@lashan/class-mediator-to-handle-null-values-in-json-payload-wso2-ei-34a43246f0f blog to address this issue

Comment: Dear Dil, the purpose of SO is so that the answer is recorded here. A link is fine as support but the solution should be here

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that link explains the opposite of what I need to achieve json null to xml empty tag, whereas I need to transform xml empty tag to empty string in json. And that task has higher priority. Nevertheless thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like restriction in wso itlsef, documentation states that is desired behavior. 
To overcome issue have try script mediator 
[WSO2ESB: Property setting not accepting empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503148/wso2esb-property-setting-not-accepting-empty-value)
or getting even lower (more complicated)
https://medium.com/@lashan/class-mediator-to-handle-null-values-in-json-payload-wso2-ei-34a43246f0f

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a more recent WSO version, there is a solution: [https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Working+with+Message+Payloads#WorkingwithMessagePayloads-EmptyXMLelementswiththe'nil'attribute](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Working+with+Message+Payloads#WorkingwithMessagePayloads-EmptyXMLelementswiththe%27nil%27attribute)

You can set synapse configs locally with the help of [JSON Transform mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/JSON+Transform+Mediator)